# How does phantomjs calculate page height?

Tags: javascript, css, pdf, height, phantomjs

I am trying to export my webpage to pdf using phantomjs.  However, when I export my webpage, it only gives me a 1 page pdf, and then it truncates the rest of the page.  However, when I change the URL from my webpage to http://reddit.com, it creates a multi-paged pdf that shows all the content.  How does phantomjs calculate page height so I can know where to start looking?

Comment: It's either a bug in PhantomJS and you should post it as a bug on GitHub or your site has a non-body element that contains the complete content and is scrollable.

Comment: Ooh, I think you are on to something.  The body of my page isn't scrollable.  Instead it has a div in it that is scrollable.  that holds the page content. So would I have to restructure my page so that the body is scrollable rather than the div?

Comment: Ideally, the browser would make the body scrollable itself when there is enough content. If you don't need the div to be scrollable, you should make the page scrollable in-full.